# Replace a column with default value using pandas if column value does not match a python list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am unable to replace a column with default value if column value does not match a python list. Tried the below code

```
originalFilePath = "C://...//someoriginalfile.csv"
newFilepath = "C://...//somenewfile.csv"
officeId_list = ("NCE6X0011", "BLR6X0253", "BOM6X0548", "LON6X0587")
df = pd.read_csv(originalFilePath)
df['officeId'] = df['officeId'].apply(lambda x: 'ABC6X0011' if x not in officeId_list else None)
df.to_csv(newFilepath, index=False)
```

Also tried some other code samples like

```
# df.loc[~df['officeId'].isin(officeId_list), 'officeId'] = 'ABC6X0011'
# df.loc[df.officeId not in officeId_list, 'officeId'] = "ABC6X0011"
```

Below column

```
officeId
KTMSQ08TE
KTMSQ08TE
```

needs to be replaced with

```
officeId
ABC6X0011
ABC6X0011
```

Comment: `df.loc[~df['officeId'].isin(officeId_list), 'officeId'] = 'ABC6X0011'` is correct, can you add some sample data for see what is problem?

Comment: I tried with this, but the data cannot be replaced. its still showing old officeIds

Comment: So it means problem is in data

Comment: Data had issues. So I want to run the program to replace the column values with a default value if it doesnt match the 4 elements in the list. All the other values in office id column have only 4 office ids that I have mentioned.

Comment: Post your full code please

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check

Comment: Problem is in data, can you test column `print (df['officeId'].head(20).tolist())` ? Is it expected ouput? No trailing whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
import pandas as pd

officeId_list = ("NCE6X0011", "BLR6X0253", "BOM6X0548", "LON6X0587")
df = pd.DataFrame({'officeId': ['KTMSQ08TE', 'KTMSQ08TE', 'BLR6X0253'] * 100000})

df['officeId'] = df['officeId'].apply(lambda x: 'ABC6X0011' if x not in officeId_list else None)
```

Returns as expected

```
         officeId
0       ABC6X0011
1       ABC6X0011
2            None
3       ABC6X0011
4       ABC6X0011
          ...
299995  ABC6X0011
299996       None
299997  ABC6X0011
299998  ABC6X0011
299999       None
```

Comment: The issue is coming for me if file has more than 300000 entries.

Comment: Add `*100000` so the line becomes: `df = pd.DataFrame({'officeId': ['KTMSQ08TE', 'KTMSQ08TE', 'BLR6X0253'] * 100000})` still no problems